# Can I do silicone caulking touch ups next day after fresh caulking?

Tags: caulking, silicone

I just caulked my bathroom using silicone but I am not happy with what I did in a few spots
Can I do some touch ups next day? This is mostly costmetic for fixing either rougher areas or uneven areas. These are corners and none of them are in the wet areas

Comment: Cured silicone repels fresh silicone. You would have to tear out the silicone and try again. You *might* have some success by rubbing down the existing silicone with denatured alcohol in hopes of achieving adhesion.

Comment: I have checked this morning and it seems that it is not that bad, the curing also kind of resorbed the rough areas and they look smooth now. The uneven width is barely noticeable ..I think I am too picky :-)

Comment: Good call, it's amazing what the threat of a do-over can achieve! =)

Comment: :-))))   Yeah we should aply that to life in general

Comment: If you're anything most people, you won't notice or care about it in a few weeks  :)